# Trying to fetch data from Nested MongoDB Database?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am beginner in MongoDB and struck at a place I am trying to fetch data from nested array but is it taking so long time as data is around 50K data, also it is not much accurate data, below is schema structure please see once -

```
    {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6001df3312ac8b33c9d26b86"
    },
    "City": "Los Angeles",
    "State":"California",
    "Details": [
      {
        "Name": "Shawn",
        "age": "55",
        "Gender": "Male", 
        "profession": " A science teacher with STEM",
        "inDate": "2021-01-15 23:12:17",
        "Cars": [
          "BMW","Ford","Opel"
        ],
        "language": "English"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Nicole",
        "age": "21",
        "Gender": "Female", 
        "profession": "Law student",
        "inDate": "2021-01-16 13:45:00",
        "Cars": [
          "Opel"
        ],
        "language": "English"
      }
    ],
    "date": "2021-01-16"
  }
```

Here I am trying to **filter date with date and Details.Cars** like

```
db.getCollection('news').find({"Details.Cars":"BMW","date":"2021-01-16"}
```

**it is returning details of other persons too which do not have cars- BMW , Only trying to display details of person like  - *Shawn* which have BMW or special array value and date too not - *Nicole*, rest should not appear but is it not happening**.

Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `$match` on the top-level fields and `$filter` on the array elements will do what you seek.

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$match: {"date":"2021-01-16"}}
    ,{$addFields: {"Details": {$filter: {
        input: "$Details",
        as: "zz",
        cond: { $in: ['BMW','$$zz.Cars'] }
        }}
    }}
    ,{$match: {$expr: { $gt:[{$size:"$Details"},0] } }}
]);
```

Notes:

1. `$unwind` is overly expensive for what is needed here and it likely means "reassembling" the data shape later.
2. We use `$addFields` where the new field to add (`Details`) *already exists*.   This effectively means "overwrite in place" and is a common idiom when filtering an array.
3. The second `$match` will eliminate docs where the `date` matches but not a single entry in `Details.Cars` is a `BMW` i.e. the array has been filtered down to zero length.  Sometimes you want to know this info so if this is the case, do not add the final `$match`.
4. I recommend you look into using real dates i.e. `ISODate` instead of strings so that you can easily take advantage of MongoDB date math and date formatting functions.

Comment: @Jeany  As a new contributor, remember as the question owner to hit both the accepted answer check mark *and* the up-arrow to give it a plus one.

Answer (score 0):

Is a common mistake think that `find({nested.array:value})` will return only the nested object but actually, this query return the whole object which has a nested object with desired value.

The query is returning the *whole* document where value `BMW` exists in the array  `Details.Cars`. So, `Nicole` is returned too.

To solve this problem:

**To get multiple elements that match the criteria** you can do an aggregation stage using `$unwind` to separate the different objects into array and match by the criteria you want.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": { "Details.Cars": "BMW", "date": "2021-01-26" }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$Details"
  },
  {
    "$match": { "Details.Cars": "BMW" }
  }
])
```

This query first match by the criteria to avoid `$unwind` over all collection.

Then `$unwind` to get every document and `$match` again to get only the documents you want.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h6TJvmbG0iL)

---

**To get only one element** (for example, if you match by `_id` and its unique) you can use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) in this way:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "Details.Cars": "BMW",
  "date": "2021-01-16"
},
{
  "Details": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "Cars": "BMW"
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3VONKBj-sVZ)

You can use `$elemenMatch` into query or projection stage. Docs [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/)

Using `$elemMatch` into query the way is this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "Details": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "Cars": "BMW"
    }
  },
  "date": "2021-01-16"
},
{
  "Details.$": 1
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aAXUUyRojLK)

The result is the same. In the second case you are using [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) to return, as docs says:

> The first element that matches the query condition on the array.

That is, the first element where `"Cars": "BMW"`.

You can choose the way you want.

Comment: but it only showing result for 1st matching array not for all arrays in newsSources, what if there are more than 5 same records, Please check here once - [Check-Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mi60vwTW_YQ)

Comment: Then you can use `$unwind` into an aggregation query. Check if [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/h6TJvmbG0iL) is correct and I updated the answer to explain it.

Comment: Thank you It works like a charm :) but what if there is another city and I have to show data in cities categories like all data of los angeles in one array and another city data in another one separately -  this - [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cj5TED2EYLG) because in your method it will separates all the array and showing one by one

Comment: If I've understood correctly I think you need `$group` to get data group by city name.